# How to extract the grants on default roles of PostgreSQL 10: pg_read_all_settings, pg_read_all_stats, pg_monitor and pg_signal_backend?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a Postgres instance of version 10 running on AWS RDS. I have a user there with default roles granted to it. I want to create the same user on my sandbox where the instance is of version 9.4. Thus, I want to know the grants that are included in these default roles of version 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-role-table-grants.html

> The view role_table_grants identifies all privileges granted on tables
>   or views where the grantor or grantee is a currently enabled role.
>   Further information can be found under table_privileges. The only
>   effective difference between this view and table_privileges is that
>   this view omits tables that have been made accessible to the current
>   user by way of a grant to PUBLIC.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55459289/6368697

Answer (score 0):

These roles are mostly hardcoded. For example, in [`pg_stat_get_activity`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/pgstatfuncs.c#L517) source code (used in `pg_stat_activity` view) - [`HAS_PGSTAT_PERMISSIONS`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/pgstatfuncs.c#L34) macros is defined as:

```
(is_member_of_role(GetUserId(), DEFAULT_ROLE_READ_ALL_STATS) || has_privs_of_role(GetUserId(), role))
```

This is direct membership check with hardcoded role name. Role was designed to grant such a possibility instead of introducing some new grant type. In versions before 10, there was only a check for superuser rights or for an exact match of the user ID: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_4_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/pgstatfuncs.c#L678

```
if (superuser() || beentry->st_userid == GetUserId())
```

And so it was impossible to grant such granular privileges.

> I want to create the same user on my sandbox where the instance is of version 9.4

Please note that RDS is a closed source fork. It is known that RDS makes its own changes in the code, including in the system of rights. Therefore, you will not be able to reproduce the RDS from outside the RDS.